# Overheating 2008 Subaru Outback

Tags: subaru, cooling-system, cooling

I have a 2008 Subaru Outback it started overheating and we change the thermostat and it continued to overheat even after burping it so we changed the radiator and all of the hoses got a new radiator cap and we have checked oil for antifreeze and antifreeze for oil nothing we've also tested the with a block tester. And that is also negative but it's still overheating only when it's in drive so when we're driving and overheats and  the heater turns cold but we can park it and rev the engine and the and the temperature gauge goes down in our heat comes back help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!